# How does one become a pujari?

Tags: scripture, vedas, temple, puja, agamas

How exactly does one become a pujari?

As in,I’d like to know what is the eligibility criteria, details of training undergone(like how interested  Christians go to a seminary and become priests after completing their degree;I did see a video long back about how a ‘gurukul’ had many children with the yajnopavit,and the tuft of hair,reciting..)

Is it possible for someone who is a convert to become a pujari?(After procuring the certificate from their closest Arya Samaj)(this is the procedure to enter the Guruvayoor Temple in Kerala,for a convert)